# delete text box dynamically

Tags: jquery

Can i delete a text box dynamically?

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far.  It would also be helpful if you didn't completely replace one question with a different question after someone has already answered.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard:I want to delete the text box automatically.If u take stackoverflow if i move a cursor on a comment ,i get a cross icon.How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

(**Edited after seeing comment in OP**):

To get StackOverflow-like functionality, you could do something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="comment">
This is a test this is a test this is a test.
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".comment").hover(function() {
    $(this).append("<span class='close'>X</span>");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("span.close").remove();
}).delegate(".close", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("div.comment").remove();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/xQTSb/

It all looks a little hectic, but here's what's going on:

- Uses [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover), which takes a function to execute on `mouseenter` and again on `mouseleave`
- Inside those functions, the `span` that removes the comment is added or removed, respectively.
- [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) is used to bind a click event to the span (necessary because the `span` does not exist until the user hovers over the `comment` div).

Comment: When i move my cursor to edge of text box,i need to have a small cross icon,if i click it should delete

Comment: @gaurav: I noticed your comment on the original post and updated my answer.

Comment: This is working in jsfiddle but not working in localost,should i need to add js1.5 and use on load.Thnx for that gr8 explanation.

Comment: @gaurav: Yes, you need to include jQuery 1.5 in the `head` element of your document, something like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_text_box_id').remove()
```

Comment: When i move my cursor to edge of text box,i need to have a small cross icon,if i click it should delete.